# Disable Webform Componotent (field) after certain number of submissions

Tags: 7, webforms

I'm working on a registration form that collects student information and the class session they're signing up to. Class sessions are of select type and has four options (sessions). Each sessions has a cap of 38 students. Is there any way to automatically disable options once submission count reaches the cap..? Please note that this is a field level condition, not the entire form level. 
Would that be rules? Any pointers... thanks!

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/342896

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this by using

hook_webform_submission_insert (which is triggered after the submission is inserted into the database)

http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21webform%21webform.api.php/function/hook_webform_submission_insert/7

Once in that hook i would use webform_get_submission_count to get the number of submissions , if this was the last allowed submission i would then unpublish the node and create a redirect to a "this class is now closed page".

http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21webform%21includes%21webform.submissions.inc/function/webform_get_submission_count/7

You could also approach it by using hook_webform_submission_presave or a custom form validator to generate a form error.